# Registreting each issue in Sentry only once

Tags: sentry

I am a big fan of Sentry, and recently I came across an article where folks stated that it's possible to configure Sentry so that it counts one issue only once. I mean, that I want to get notified about a certain issue only once as it has occurred the first time, and then ignore all subsequent occurences. However, after I resolve the issue, if it happens again, I would like to receive a notification about that (and still only once).
Does Sentry support such sort of stuff ?
I have read the [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/quotas/#filter-by-issue) twice, didn't find anything similar.
https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/quotas/#filter-by-issue

Comment: Sentry should notify you already only once for each issue. An issue is a group of similar events, grouped by their fingerprint (mainly based on the stacktrace if available)

Comment: Wel, yes. It actually notifies only once, but the counter of events is still increasing each time the same error happens, and this make my quota run out very quickly !